# Can someone expalin me how facebook stores the start and end time of events?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, timezone

I got from various sources that Facebook stores The start and end time of events as PST. But there must be something I'm missing. Take this facebook [event](https://www.facebook.com/events/465872263429982/) which I created. I live in Italy and in fact when I insert the event time it says UTC + 2. I insert `2012-05-18 10.30 PM` as the event start time.  I Expect this to be saved as 1.30 PM Pacific time, because PST should be GMT -7 (because of daylight saving time). But if I do

```
$start = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $facebook_event['start_time'] );
```

`$start` comes out `2012-05-19 05:30:00` which is 7 hours after the time I inserted! How is that possible? what am I missing?

EDIT - this is how I retrieve the event start_time

```
        $fql = "SELECT 
                    eid,
                    name,
                    description,
                    start_time,
                    end_time,
                    venue,
                    location,
                    update_time
                FROM
                    event
                WHERE 
                    eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = $id)" ;
        $events = $facebook->api( array(
            'method' => 'fql.query',
            'query' => $fql,
        ) );
```

I don't use the `/$id/events/` api call because I always get back an empty set when I get my friends events

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944729/event-time-displaying-incorrectly-for-my-facebook-event-submitted-via-javascrip

Comment: check this also http://forrst.com/posts/Facebook_Event_Times_and_their_Ridiculous_Timezo-CN5

Comment: @VenuGopalT i'm using fql to get back the data and i get a timestamp, thanks for the links, i'v read lot's of them but couldn't figure out anything.

Comment: simply fb_stored_time = epoch(UTC(assumed_Pacific_time))

Comment: @VenuGopalT and to decode that back to UTC?

Comment: you're going to have to manually offset difference between PST and the time zone of the user that entered the event into facebook

Comment: @VenuGopalT ok, but in my example, why when i saved 10.30 PM at UTC +2 he saved 5.30 AM of the next day?I would have though he would save 1.30PM of the same day because PST is UTC - 7. He saved UTC +5

Comment: let me explain, You inserted 2012-05-18 10.30 PM in EST but facebook assumes you are sending it in pacific time.

Comment: @VenuGopalT now you explained perfectly. if you write that as an answer i will accept that :)

Comment: when it converts to UTC it becomes 2012-05-19 05:30:00 which you are reciveing. This would clear things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

let me explain the Facebook timezone rules,

Facebook always assumes start_time or end_time you are sending are in pacific timezone. so its our responsibility to send them in pacific timezone.

In above case, 
You inserted 2012-05-18 10.30 PM in EST but Facebook assumes that you are sending it in pacific time. so it converts in to UTC as 2012-05-19 05:30:00. which you will recive throuh API.

simply fb_stored_time = epoch(UTC(assumed_Pacific_time))

Comment: It's amazing that they get away with this… I guess the world really does revolve around California.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your script before the date function.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```